# Связывание таблиц в базе данных

Tags: sql

В базе данных есть 2 таблицы:
В первой: название фирмы, системы рейтинга и оценка (буква) (Ag_name, Rat_name, Grade)

[image: Первая таблица]

Во второй: система рейтинга и оценки в (число)

[image: Вторая таблица]

Как правильно связать таблицы, чтобы потом можно было построить график и чтобы оценка изменялась с буквы на цифру
Графики строю на Python

Answer (score 0):

Один ко многим, и от оценок строить рейтинг, считая каунт по связи

Comment: а можно банальный пример на SQL?